# Can i use 2*7.4 Lipo to obtain 11.1v

Tags: lipo, batteries

I am a newbie, i have 2*7.4v LiPo, i need 11.1v, can i wire 2 of the charging wires of 1st lipo to another to obtain 11.1v(1S+2S=3S), will it be safe as i have heard that lipo's are less stable.

Comment: If you know enough about Lipos to be able to hack them safely, you probably won't find such a hack worthwhile anyway. To answer your question: Whether it's safe or not depends on how you do it. If I were you, I'd get hold of a 3S lipo instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to draw a low amount of current (1C) you'll have no trouble because the balancing wires are far less thin than power cables. Since the connection will be in series you don't have to worry about damaging your cells.

Comment: i need it to run a coaxial, around 10C, both wires seem same to me, should i use it, though i am worried the wires i will be using to connect the two batteries, what choices do i have, it seems to the charging port support only jumper wires.

Comment: 10C is a really big amount of current, those connectors are not designed to run such a great demand of power, they're just for charging purposes, so anything more than 1C could damage the connectors. For such a big amount of current maybe you should look for a DC DC converter that satisfies your needs.

Comment: you are talking about the connectors inside the battery,right?

Comment: It would damage all the system that goes from the balancing connectors (those which you plug in the balancer charger) to the connections inside the battery that connect each cell to the balancing wires.